# Sequence transformations in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In scala, is there a simple way of transforming this sequence

`Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("c", 4), ("b", 5))`

into this `Seq(("a", 4), ("b", 7), ("c", 4))`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you meant to have `String`s in the second ordinate of the tuple. Assuming `Seq[(String, Int)]`, you can use `groupBy` to group the elements by the first ordinate:

```
Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("c", 4), ("b", 5))
   .groupBy(_._1)
   .mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
   .toSeq
```

Otherwise, you'll next an extra `.toInt`

Comment: That was a tupo. I've edited my question. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: It's worth noting that this won't maintain order.

Comment: `groupBy` will scramble the order, yes.

Comment: similar solution: 
s.groupBy(_._1).map{case (k,v)=> (k,v.map{case(s,i) => i}.sum)}.toSeq

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way by unzipping and using the second item in the tuple.

```
val sq = sqSeq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("c", 4), ("b", 5))
sq.groupBy(_._1)
  .transform {(k,lt) => lt.unzip._2.sum}
  .toSeq
```

The above code details:

```
scala> sq.groupBy(_._1)
res01: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[(String, Int)]] = Map(b -> List((b,2), (b,5)), a -> List((a,1), (a,3)), c -> List((c,4)))

scala> sq.groupBy(_._1).transform {(k,lt) => lt.unzip._2.sum}
res02: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 7, a -> 4, c -> 4)


scala> sq.groupBy(_._1).transform {(k,lt) => lt.unzip._2.sum}.toSeq
res03: Seq[(String, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((b,7), (a,4), (c,4))
```